# How to Convert array of CSV formatted Strings into an array of JSON objects

Tags: java

My code as follows:

```
private static JsonArray convertExternalLeadDataToJson(String input[]) {
    JsonArray output = new JsonArray();

    // Loop through each CSV row in array
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Split CSV row into separate fields
        List items = Arrays.asList(input[i].split(","));

        // Add fields to JSON object
        JsonObject lead = new JsonObject();
       
        
          lead.add("firstName", items.get(0)); 
          lead.add("lastName", items.get(1)); 
          lead.add("email", items.get(2)); 
          lead.add("title", items.get(3));
         
        output.add(lead);
    }
    return output;
}
```

For this I am getting error as "The method add(String, int) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, Object)".

Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your CSV data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonObjectBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html), it helps to create a Json object.

```
JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Split CSV row into separate fields
        List items = Arrays.asList(input[i].split(","));

        // Add fields to JSON object
        JsonObject lead = factory.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("firstName", items.get(0))
            .add("lastName", items.get(1))
            .add("email", items.get(2)) 
            .add("title", items.get(3))
            .build();
         
        output.add(lead);
    }
```